# convert excel data to text file particular blocks format using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to python related to data parsing or formatting. I have a use-case where I have excel sheet created by a tool, which consists of configuration data in rows and columns I would like to convert to normal text file in a particular blocks enclosed with `{}` like defining variable keys.

Here is a my Excel sheet:
[image: The input Excel sheet]

Here is the code i converted my excel to text but it contained data with many NAN and relevant data as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('enum_dns.xlsx', sheet_name='DNS-NG', engine='openpyxl')

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    df.to_string(outfile)
```

**Desired output**:

```
 dns-local::udp-tcp v-xnmmsite1-e2-local {
      description="Edge-2 xnmm/Dns Traffic" 
      state="ENABLED" 
      address=[10.x.x.x] 
      port=53 
      udp-settings {
         thread-count=1 
         packet-size=512
      } 
      tcp-settings {
         backlog=50 
         read-timeout=180
      }
   }

   dns-peer::client ims-site-a {
      state="ENABLED" 
      context="xnmmdns-context" 
      binding=&v-xnmmsite1-e2-local 
      address::SUBNET=10.x.x.x/23 
      tcp-settings {
         maximum-connections=100 
         read-timeout=180
      }
   }
```

Comment: a) Is your input an Excel? It is not very easy to see the columns and where they end. b) What is the desired output? Is it what you label as *output*?

Comment: @YannisP. I have attached InputSheet as picture in above post . Also Output is expected in text format like above mention in the post.

Comment: I made a small edit to embed your image in the post. Your question is rather complicated and your data model is not really easy to understand. Perhaps as a first line of attack, it would make some more sense for you to divide, the different tables your have in your Excel files, into _different Excel sheets_, they can be at least read efficiently by `pandas`. Otherwise, it is rather hard to do it right now.

Comment: @YannisP. Yes i think so i m thinking to make custom excel asper my ease and propse excel providing team to give data in that formst to mske program works. I will paste my code for some doubts here after modifications

Comment: Hi @YannisP. I have made changes in excel sheet i m able to achieve 80% of my target . I am stuck on point . In My excel image embedded in above post there are some are optional parameters with yellow higlighted font ** and **while font one mandatory parameters. Is there any way to get these column details as per their font colour or highlighted colour so that we can mark them as mandatory and optional . my Current Code to achieve my previous usecase :
[link] (https://github.com/kashifiqbalece/exceltoconftext/blob/master/mainfolder%2Fmain.py)